# How to use if or ternary operator in underscore template

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

```
<script type="text/template" id="list-template">
    <td class="title"><span><%-from['name'] %></span></td>
    <td>
    <div class="title"><span><%- message ? message : '' %></span>

    </td>
    
    <td><span><%-id %> </td>
                             
</script>
```

Error is:

> ReferenceError: message is not defined
>
> `((__t=( message ? message : '' ))==null?'':_.escape(__t))+`

Comment: OK, so what is `message` supposed to be? Also, why is this tagged [php]?

Comment: ok. ignore php word. actuay i m fetching data from facebook api. so with some posts there is no message. it should print blank if there is no message key in the array.

Comment: You should post how you are invoking the template function and sample of data being passed to it

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a JS expression, such as a ternary operator, you should use the `<% expression %>` syntax. You can use this directly in your template with `<% message ? print(message) : print('') %>`.

A better way would be to evaluate the expression within your JS code and pass the evaluated value into the template:

`var tpl = _.template("<div>Some text: <%= message %></div>");
tpl({ message: message || ''})`